# Call PHP function after a timeout

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP application, where a SMS is sent to a person and waits "x" minutes for that person to login to the system. If the person doesn't login to the system during "X" minutes, the database will be updated accordingly and the next person waiting will be informed.

I am trying to find a way to call a function after "X" minutes so that the database will be updated and the next user will be informed. I want to do this without polling the database every second to check whether the first user has logged in or not. I am trying to find a way to check once after the "X" minutes have elapsed and then inform the next user. Something like Javascript's `settimeout` function.

I want to do this from the server side, and the solution should work on windows or linux platforms.

Please advice

Thank you!

I came across, the PEAR package "Event-dispatcher" but there is no way to call the events based on a timeout. The PECL, "Event" doesn't seem to support in my hosting providers server.

Comment: How about 'polling' every few minutes? For instance with a cron job.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware . Since the waiting time (X minutes) is set by the user, I don't  want to guess the time and poll the database. Because then it wont be real-time.  I am trying to minimize the overhead of polling every few minutes.

Comment: Use a queue library like e.g. [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) which uses redis to maintain a queue. That way the timeout will just cause the next thing in the queue to start being processed.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos thank you. This seems interesting I will certainly check this out and update you here.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos. Im sorry Im dont have enough reputation points to upvote your comment. How do I set a timeout in that library?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it but each queue is ran by the queue worker which is essentially just running a PHP process. If you have something like `set_timeout(X)` within your queued job code then that should work as a means to ensure no job takes longer than X seconds. Your task would then be to add something to the queue. The worker will dequeue the first task and work on it and when that's done dequeue the next one.

Comment: Full disclaimer. I've commented instead of answering because this is a hard problem and you will need to do quite some setting up to get it to work. Queue is (imo) the simplest way to do this but I can't really offer a full solution, that you will have to investigate more on.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos. Thank you. I appreciate you taking time to comment and suggest. I will read more on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a pure PHP solution for the aforementioned.

My workaround was, delegating this task to a servelt (java) which can run a method after a timeout. My servlet, upon receiving a request will start a timeout and then send a response back to my PHP application when the timeout is up.

So far this was the best solution I could find.